# Paint doesn't draw at cursor position

Tags: windows-7, microsoft-paint

I faced a problem while drawing something in MS-paint, the dot in the picture is where the cursor is and it draws somewhere else! How should I fix it?

[image]

Comment: Please give something like GIMP a try, its a free ware editor, is the same thing happening? also.. can you click icons on the desktop normally?? and is it possible a touch screen/ or digitzer screen?

Comment: It appears that you are using a touch screen or digitizer.  Is this correct?

Comment: @Nick2253: No, I don't even use mouse. It's laptop touch-pad.

Comment: If you use a mouse (like a USB mouse), does this still happen?

Comment: @Nick2253: No, it doesn't.

Comment: @ppumkin: Yes, I click desktop icons normally.

Comment: It sounds like a problem with your touchpad drivers.  Uninstall them, and then re-download the latest ones from your laptop manufacturer's support page.

Comment: @Nick2253: I will do and will let you know if it works, thank you.

Comment: Perhaps your mouse pad is wet, or has a single drop of fluid somewhere on the right?

Comment: @JJ_Jason: No, it's not.

Comment: @Gigili: Is the cursor at a different place? It's not shown in the screenshot so it's hard to tell...

Comment: @TomWijsman: The small dot is the cursor, I couldn't do anything else to make it clearer, sorry.

Comment: @Gigili: Given your cursor's location, I think I'm onto something. If you draw a `L`, does it just draw that the same in the lower right side or does it mirror that somehow?

Comment: @TomWijsman: The former.

Comment: @Gigili: I've placed an answer at the same time as my comment, did that answer work?

Comment: Yes, I just saw it. I'll let you know, thank you for the time you spent to find the answer @TomWijsman.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Ah, doing a Google search I came on [a YouTube video](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=P-GrX-K8_8U) which mentions a solution:

> 1. Clicked start.
> 2. Went to the Control Panel.
> 3. Typed "cursor" in the Search of the top left hand corner of Control Panel window.
> 4. Clicked "change the mouse pointer display or speed".
> 5. Go to the Pointer Options tab.
> 6. Remove the check from Enhanced Pointer Precision.

Comment: While the answer above works as well, sometimes the box is already unchecked. While it sounds silly, if the box is unchecked, checking it can actually be a fix. Strange, but it works!

Answer (score 0):

1. Click Start
2. Go to control panel
3. To the right of where it says *Adjust your computer's settings* there will be a *view by* button. Select large/small icons.
4. Click *Mouse*
5. A window will pop up. Go to the *pointer options* tab
6. Under *pointer speed* there will be a check-box that says *enhance pointer precision*. If it is checked uncheck in and if it is unchecked, check it.

Answer (score 0):

Control Menu>Hardware>Mouse>Pointer Options> Click twice the "Ehance Pointer Precision". Some people are used to having the precision on. There is no need to change it if you feel uncomfy with/without it. A simple re-click on the tick box helps.

Comment: Welcome to SuperUser! Thank you for your answer, but there's an exact same answer which is also the accepted answer.